# How to get the "calculated" path in PHP?

Tags: php, path

```
$p = '/var/www/domain/a/b/../..';
```

How to write such a function `func` so that `func($p)` equals to `'/var/www/domain/'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath).

Example:

```
$p = '/var/www/domain/a/b/../..';
$q = realpath($p); // will result in /var/www/domain or FALSE on failure
```

Cases in which `realpath()` returns false, as quoted from the manual:

> `realpath()` returns FALSE on failure,
>   e.g. if the file does not exist.
>
> **Note:**
>
> The running script must have
>   executable permissions on all
>   directories in the hierarchy,
>   otherwise `realpath()` will return
>   FALSE.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the script needs the correct permissions on `/var/` and `/var/www/` for `realpath()` to work here.